# How do I replace a line with sed with /

Tags: regex, linux, sed

Hello I currently have a file in this format:

```
This  is a test file

location = /home/files
```

My question is how do I replace this line `location = /home/files` with this `location = /home/documents/test_files`?

Comment: Is `This is a test file` part of the file? Is there anything else in the file. Have you tried anything to do this. There are a large number of questions on this site about making changes to files.

Comment: Yes This is a test file is part of the file and there is nothing else in the file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When there's a "/" in the original string, or replacement string, we muse use "\" to escape "/". Alternatively you can use any character as substitution delimiter, such as "@"

```
$ cat sample.csv 
This  is a test file

location = /home/files

$ sed 's@/home/files@/home/documents/test_files@' sample.csv 
This  is a test file

location = /home/documents/test_files
```

Answer (score 1):

Just choose a different delimiter:

```
sed 's-location = /home/files-location = /home/documents/test_files-' test.txt
sed 's~location = /home/files~location = /home/documents/test_files~' test.txt
```

Or escape the `/`:

```
sed 's/location = \/home\/files/location = \/home\/documents\/test_files/' test.txt
```